# Проблема с изменением размера ProgressBar

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, android-xml

Есть `ProgressBar`

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/progress_bar_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/progress_bar_height"
    android:rotation="-90"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/shape_circular"
    />
```

Для него установлена фиксированная ширина и высота. Проблема заключается в том, что  когда я для него использую `android:progressDrawable` такого вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
   android:shape="ring"
   android:thickness="6sp"
   >

   <solid android:color="@color/colorGreen"/> 

</shape>
```

То размер прогресс бара соответствует установленным  значениям.

Но когда я хочу сделать `ProgressBar` с `progress` и  `secondaryProgress` 
и использую в качестве `progressDrawable` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  >
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
            <shape
                android:shape="ring"
                android:useLevel="true"
                android:thickness="5sp">

                <!--<gradient-->
                    <!--android:startColor="#f9f7f7"-->
                    <!--android:endColor="#d91111"-->
                    <!--android:type="sweep" />-->
                <solid android:color="#d91111"/>
            </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
            <shape
                android:innerRadius="55dp"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:useLevel="true"
                android:thickness="6.0sp">
                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="0"
                    android:toDegrees="360"
                    />
                <!--<gradient-->
                    <!--android:startColor="#70ed70"-->
                    <!--android:endColor="#f4f7f4"-->
                    <!--android:type="sweep" />-->

                <solid android:color="#70ed70"/>
            </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

то размер уменьшается в два раза, не понятно почему. Разница в размере видно на картинках.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверное вот в этом дело: `android:innerRadius="55dp"`

Answer (score 1):

`android:innerRadius="55dp"` убери, в первом примере у тебя его нет.

Comment: убрал, не помогло, я его устанавливал что  бы между зеленым и красным кругом была разница, иначе по контуру зеленого круга немного заметен контур красного круга, в любом случае - это не помогло!

Comment: android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3" куда пропало? Может быть в этом дело?